# Cannot install Rails 6 due to annobin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote my first major rails app in 2008 and have been using it since. Over the years I've installed it at least 10 times. Now I cannot install Rails 6. The installation fails at nokogiri with the following error in /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/nokogiri-1.10.9/mkmf.log:

cc1: fatal error: inaccessible plugin file /usr/local/gcc8/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/plugin/annobin.so expanded from short plugin name annobin: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:

```
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
```

/* end */

I've tried to learn what annobin is with no luck. I've attempted to install annobin from github, but that does not provide the functionality rails is looking for. Of course, this little program compiles and runs just fine. So I have no idea why rails now requires annobin to install. In this context I'm not even sure what a plugin is.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Annobin (annotated bin) is described here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Toolchain/Watermark.  Basically it adds metadata to binaries to provide extra information about the build environment.  RoR remains fundamentally an experimental project which continues to enlarge and adapt testing methodologies as part of its core process.  Annobin is just another item added to that list.

Comment: I've read that page. It contains the concept for annobin and gives specifications. There is nothing about implementation. I'm running Fedora 31. I installed annobin via ```sudo dnf install annobin``` but that does not solve the problem and doesn't give an annobin.so which seems to be what rails (nokogiri) wants. So next I tried the rpm package from rpmfind.net. That could not be installed giving the error message ```unable to install annobin: could not depsolve transaction; 1 problem detected:``` There is no further message. gcc version 8.3.0 (GCC). Linux 5.5.11-200.fc31.x86_64

Comment: I solved this problem by using sudo dnf reinstall annobin and then copying the annobin.so files to the location listed in mkmf.log. Somehow the first installation was incomplete. man annobin does not list files that are supposed to be installed. Thanks for your comment. I hadn't thought that feature creep could apply to developers and is not just for end users.

Comment: In my case the error was due to using an upgraded GCC toolset (appstream). Installing the matching plugin resolved the issues - 'sudo dnf install gcc-toolset-nn-annobin-plugin-gcc'